# How to pip install a remote tar.gz file via SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, server, pip

After looking at many other SO q&a, I don't seem to find the one that fits my case, quite surprising since it seems a fairly common thing to me.

I want to `pip install` a `tar.gz` file over ssh, but unlike the other posts I find, it is not located on Git or any other online service, it is privately hosted in my server.

So basically, in my client I want to do something like:

`pip install ssh://user@myserver/path/to/package.tar.gz`

or anything with the form:
`pip install [WHATGOESHERE?]/path/to/package.tar.gz`

The server has the client keys so no password will be asked. Or maybe it is `ftp` instead of `ssh`?

I know I could first retrieve the file via `scp`, and then install it locally, but that is not what I want to do here. Thanks!

Comment: "pip install" does not seem to accept `ssh://`. You can start a http server on `myserver` with `python -m http.server` and run `pip install http://...`

Comment: Another approach is to use [tag:sshfs] and install the archive as if it's on the local filesystem.

Comment: Thanks @Philippe, in fact, my server already has an http server, and it is how I "publish" the official releases among my work colleagues who do as you say, but I wanted something more for the development side, so for the moment I put the "dev.tar.gz" on a hidden folder, but I still don't quite like it :)

Comment: yes, I do have nfs mounted between linux machines, and sshfs between windows/linux machines... my question arose from a more fundamental point of view, in the sense that I couldn't quite believe this cannot be done in the way I suggest... later I have found out that ``pip install`` does not read from stdin, so it cannot be "piped". I have tried with another approach, with ``xargs`` such that ``scp host:/path/file.tar.gz >(xargs pip install)`` but this throws some weird Unicode errors....